# How to convert a date to a number, so that the number represents how far it is from the first date in python in an efficient way?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a range of dates from 2013-1-1 to 2017-1-1 i want to represent them as days from the first day;

eg: 2013-1-1 will be 1, 2013-1-2 will be 2... all the way to 2017-1-1

trying to save memory is also important.

right now my dates are in a datetime index and i only have the .dayofyear method and it doesn't help me.

i have tried the apply() function along with .to_ordinal but this takes up a lot of memory as apply return an object, methods like .dayofyear work on underlying int64 so they save memory so any method like this will help, thanks

i am trying to plot values obtained on different dates since 2013

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.timedelta` represents differences between dates, you can use its `.days` property to find out how many days they are apart:

```
first = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1)
second = datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)

delta = second - first

print(second, "is day", delta.days + 1)

delta = first - first

print(first, "is day", delta.days + 1)
```

If you use this a lot, you could put it into a function:

```
def day_number(from_date):
    def inner(to_date):
        delta = to_date - from_date
        return delta.days + 1
    return inner
```

Usage:

```
>>> since_2013 = day_number(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1))
>>> since_2013(datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1))
1462
>>> since_2013(datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1))
1
```